# Cross Compatible Browser coding for CSS3 webkit animations?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Curious to find out I am able to implement the following `webkit-animation` into non-webkit browser, such as Firefox, Internet Explorer and Opera? What would the coding be?

```
@-webkit-keyframes FadeIn {
   0% {
    opacity:0;
      }
   100% {
    opacity:1;
      }
}

.object {
    -webkit-animation-name: FadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@-webkit-keyframes FadeIn
{
        0%
        {
                opacity:0;
        }
        100%
   {
                opacity:1;
        }
}
@-webkit-keyframes FadeOut
{
        0%
        {
                opacity:1;
        }
        100%
   {
                opacity:0;
        }
}
@-moz-keyframes FadeIn
{
  from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes FadeOut
{
  from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; }
}
@-o-keyframes FadeIn
{
  from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes FadeOut
{
  from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; }
}
@keyframes FadeIn
{
  from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; }
}
@keyframes FadeOut
{
  from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; }
}
#example
{
-webkit-animation:FadeIn ease-in 0.5s;
-moz-animation:FadeIn ease-in 0.5s;
-o-animation:FadeIn ease-in 0.5s;
animation:FadeIn ease-in 0.5s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

IE does not support the CSS3 Transitions. More advices from [here](http://css3please.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Guess you can use

```
-moz-animation:
```

for mozilla and

```
-o-animation:
```

for opera.

Internet explorer does not support the same

You could check this link for more info http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp